# iOS Dynamic Type - preventing change of TableView Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app I have a Table View, the table view has a mixture of custom cells and the default cells (UITableViewCellStyleValue1).

What I observe is, on iOS 7 when the system font is changed, my custom cells donot change their size, however the default cells change their font size and are quite illegible. So is the case for the section headers. 

It is important that the fonts remain as is for the table view to look good. 

Is there a way so that I can prevent the Section Headers and the default table cells from changing their font size?

Comment: I share this issue. The only answer I've found thus far is to stop putting text in the default textLabel or detailTextLabel.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37549824/1971013) is how.