# Ignoring the dynamic type in iOS: Accessibility

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, accessibility

Is there a way to completely ignore dynamic type/font size settings in iOS apps?
I mean is there a way like a plist entry so that I can disable it completely. I understand there is a notification we can observe and re-configure the font whenever there is change in the settings. I am looking for a simpler solution. I am using iOS8.
Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic type is something you have to actively implement (or at least select within the Interface Builder). It doesn't *just work*.

Comment: If I go and change the font size in phone's settings app and come back to my app, the font gets changed. I have done nothing for this.

Comment: What font are you using in Interface Builder?

Comment: Haven't used interface builder/storyboard. Have set font in code to some float value.

Comment: Could you show me the code?

Comment: @FabioPoloni yes it is automatically work is you use the default UITableViewCell labels

Comment: Don't use text styles if you don't want to enable Dynamic Type because it only works for text with implemented text styles.

Answer (score 10):

There's no need to swizzle `UIApplication`.   Just subclass `UIApplication` and provide your own implementation of `preferredContentSizeCategory`:

Swift:

```
class MyApplication: UIApplication {

    override var preferredContentSizeCategory: UIContentSizeCategory {
        get { return UIContentSizeCategory.large }
    }
}

UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
    NSStringFromClass(MyApplication.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Objective-C:

```
@interface MyApplication : UIApplication
@end

@implementation MyApplication

- (UIContentSizeCategory) preferredContentSizeCategory
{
    return UIContentSizeCategoryLarge;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Works in iOS 11.  While implementing this, I learned that I've been doing all my development work on my iPhone with my "Larger Text" slider set to `UIContentSizeCategoryExtraLarge` (one size up from the default).  There's no way to know the default in Settings or reset to the default (except by using a fresh simulator).  The "Larger Text" slider is always active (even with the switch off).  When the switch is ON, the slider has more range.

Answer (score 5):

In your `AppDelegate` add:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

NSString* swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return UIContentSizeCategoryLarge;  // Set category you prefer, Large being iOS' default.
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(preferredContentSizeCategory));
    method_setImplementation(method, (IMP)swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory);

    ...
}
```

Comment: @zeeple Should be possible. I only have it in Obj-C. I tried to quickly convert to Swift 2.2, but this requires sorting out all kinds of typical Swift selector and type related issues; have no time to do that now. Please post an answer with your Swift version.

Comment: This solution for me works only when launching fresh the app. If the user by any chance modifies the font size and resumes the app right after, this solution won't cover that scenario. :(

Answer (score 4):

Just provide Swift 4 fix to [@gebirgsbärbel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814783/ignoring-the-dynamic-type-in-ios-accessibility/48149712#48149712) answer.
"preferredContentSizeCategory" in Objective-C is a method, but in Swift it is a read-only variable. So in your AppDelegate is like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        UIApplication.classInit

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        ...
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}

// MARK: - Fix Dynamic Type

extension UIApplication {

    static let classInit: Void = {
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, #selector(getter: fixedPreferredContentSizeCategory))!,
            class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, #selector(getter: preferredContentSizeCategory))!
        )
    }()

    @objc
    var fixedPreferredContentSizeCategory: UIContentSizeCategory {
        return .large
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The swift equivalent to the answer of @meaning-matters looks as follows:

In your AppDelegate:

```
@objc func swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory() -> UIContentSizeCategory {
    return UIContentSizeCategory.small
}

open func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, #selector(preferredContentSizeCategory))
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, #selector(swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory))
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory)
}
```

Comment: When I try to use this, I get compiler errors: `Use of unresolved identifier 'preferredContentSizeCategory'`. Is there something else that's needed to make it work?

Comment: My best guess was changing the selectors to `getter: UIApplication.preferredContentSizeCategory` and `MyAppDelegate.swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory` along with a couple other changes, which cleared the compiler errors but it doesn't seem to do anything when it runs.