# Dynamic type , Disable auto refresh UITableVIew when setting/text size is changed in iOS 8 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8

I have `UITableView` in my `UIViewController`, When I change the text size in device setting and come back to my app, `UITableView` will get refreshed.

Its happens only on iOS 8.x and later,

My Question

Is it possible to disable auto-refresh the `UITableView` at the time of Dynamic type?

Steps to reproduce,

1. Open the app,
2. Press Home button and app will go to Background,
3. Go to Setting/Display & Brightness/Text Size and change the font size by dragging slider,
4. Come back to our app,
5. `applicationWillEnterForeground` delegate method gets called, After that `UITableView` `delegate` methods are getting called in `UIViewController`.

**Note:** `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods are not getting called.

Please can any one help me.

Comment: I think dynamic type changes trigger the UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, but I'm sorry that I have not looked into its implementation. A not-very-elegant solution would be to use booleans to track this state change

Comment: Perhaps using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37549824/1971013) will avoid getting the refresh.