# Disabling Dynamic Type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

I have a Sprite Kit based game that uses a UIView within one of the scenes, and I do that so that I can take advantage of the UITableViewController to present a game settings screen.

The difficulty I am running into is that when a user sets their iPad system accessibility settings to use (extra) large type, the text within the UITableView is too large for the cells and it looks just plain silly.

What I would like to do is straight up disable the dynamic type within the app so it always displays the same sized type in the cells.

I have found another similar posting ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814783/ignoring-the-dynamic-type-in-ios-accessibility)) but the response offers an Objective-C response:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

NSString* swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    return UIContentSizeCategoryLarge;  // Set category you prefer, Large being iOS' default.
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(preferredContentSizeCategory));
    method_setImplementation(method, (IMP)swizzled_preferredContentSizeCategory);

    ...
}
```

I need to do this in Swift.

What is the correct way to do this same thing in Swift in Xcode 7+ ?

Comment: This is a lazy cop-out for a feature that's very important, in-fact necessary, for many users. Don't cut corners like this.

Comment: @AMomchilov I agree!  And in fact my team just discussed it and we will implement this feature in a future revision, but for now we just need the tables to not look wonky.  So in fact, it is a temporary band-aid.  Thanks for your comment, tho.

Comment: @zeeple Tables not looking bad was exactly the reason why I implemented the above code. I also made sure that my has a rather large and readable default font side.

Comment: An app I work on had many requests from users to be able to disable dynamic type in-app. It seems people prefer to have dynamic type enabled for some apps but not others. So there _are_ legitimate reasons to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first let me say this:  while I am happy that I was able to quickly find a way to accommodate the dynamic text provided by the iOS accessibility settings (which I will show the code for in a sec) I think it is still important to get an answer to the original question.

That said, here is what I did to the table view code to respect the larger type that some users need.  It was a two step process.  First, add:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

to the viewDidLoad method.  Then, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, add the following before you return the cell:

```
cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
```

Good luck folks, and please add an answer to the original question if you have one :)

Comment: The question dealt with disabling the Dynamic Type feature in your app, not adapting the larger type in your table view cells?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [@zeeple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711558/8408940) for the solution.
Here is the answer to the original question:

"preferredContentSizeCategory" in Objective-C is a method, but in Swift it is a read-only variable.

So in your AppDelegate is like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        UIApplication.classInit

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        ...
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}

// MARK: - Fix Dynamic Type

extension UIApplication {

    static let classInit: Void = {
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, #selector(getter: fixedPreferredContentSizeCategory))!,
            class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, #selector(getter: preferredContentSizeCategory))!
        )
    }()

    @objc
    var fixedPreferredContentSizeCategory: UIContentSizeCategory {
        return .large
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to do is straight up **disable the dynamic type within the app** so it always displays the same sized type in the cells.

Dynamic Type only works for text with implemented [text styles](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html#TextStyles).

So, if you always want to **disable Dynamic Type** and **display the same sized type in the cells**, don't use text styles nor [image size adjustment](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html#Images) in them.

However, if you do want to use the text styles, never tick `Automatically Adjusts Font` for each text element in Interface Builder *(equivalent to `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`in code)*.

Answer (score 1):

Hi All Frustrated Devs,

Here is perfect solution to disable Dynamic Type is :

Since **iOS 15** you can set limits on the minimum and maximum sizes of dynamic type. It works for both UIKit and SwiftUI.

```
// UIKit

view.minimumContentSizeCategory = .medium
view.maximumContentSizeCategory = .accessibilityExtraLarge

// SwiftUI

ContentView()
  .dynamicTypeSize(.medium ... .accessibility3)
```

Also if you want to directly disable throughout the whole Application, You should create a **Base Class** which should be **parent of your all VCs**. In **BaseVC** you can set up code.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI I overrode it for all views in my hierarchy as follows:

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.sizeCategory, .large)
        }
    }
}
```